# Is there any way in Portainer when using Git Repository Stack to also include a configuration file or any workaround?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, configuration, portainer

I want to deploy Traefik using Portainer Git Repository Stack however it also needs a traefik.yml configuration file. I do not want to have to copy it from git and put it into a bind-mount location manually. This goes for any other image needing configuration as well.

Is there a way in which one or more configuration files can be copied from git as part of the automatic stack deployment?

I have seen some docker-compose files include containers for initial setups before although in a separate context. I can see this as perhaps being a workaround where a git checkout is done and then a file copy. Not sure how this should be done properly though.

An example docker-compose.yml file for Traefik

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:latest"
    container_name: "traefik"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        # traefik.yml needs to be placed here
        source: ~/docker/traefik/config 
        target: /etc/traefik
      - type: bind
        source: /var/run/docker.sock
        target: /var/run/docker.sock:ro
```